# MySQL - Tipos para CPF, RG e CNPJ

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Fala galera.
Estou no começo ainda de MySQL e estou com uma dúvida em relação a tipos de campos em RG, CPF, CNPJ.
Eu dei uma pesquisada mas só encontro respostas de anos atrás, então precisaria de algo mais atualizado.
Se eu não me engano, RG não possui quantidade de caracteres fixos como CNPJ e CPF, então qual deveria usar?
Além disso CPF e CNPJ se eu não me engano, podem possuir zero na frente, então uso `char`?
Eu pensei em usar os tipos abaixo:

```
cpf char(14)
cnpj char(18)
```

Coloquei em char para que o zero na frente apareça, e colocarei pontos e traços por meio de máscara em JS.
O que eu fiquei em dúvida é o RG, por que não sei se existem RGs com zero na frente, mas não poderia usar `char` pois até onde eu sei, não possui número fixo de caracteres.
Obrigado.

Comment: No caso de RG você pode utilizar `varchar` de 15 por exemplo. Eu recomendo você não armazenar cpf e cnpj sem as pontuações, ai seus campos seriam `char(11)` para cpf e `char(14)` para cnpj.

Comment: Olá Roberto. Por que não recomendaria armazenar com as pontuações? Obrigado!

Comment: Porque todas as vezes que você ter que fazer alguma procura por cpf terá que colocar as pontuações, fora que, ocupa mais espaço no seu banco de dados.

Comment: A questão de comparação acho eu que não seria problema pois como eu usarei máscara para inserir os pontos e traços, automaticamente irá ficar no padrão cadastrado, mas sobre o ocupar mais espaço faz sentido hahaha Obrigado!

Comment: "eu recomendo você não armazenar sem as pontuações" acho que quis dizer o contrário, mas eu recomendo a armazenar com as pontuações, igualmente telefone, espaço de 5 caracteres, pouco importa hoje em dia, apesar de ser necessário realizar cálculo para validar CPF/CNPJ , só é necessário validar uma vez, já a máscara, vai ter que aplicar em cada select. Já fiz das duas formas e o melhor pra mim foi armazenar com a máscara. Na consulta, basta limpar a máscara na query

Comment: Os comentários aqui não fazem muito sentido, uma hora fala em por pontuações e depois fala que tirar as pontuações ocupa mais espaço. Não deve usar pontuação porque isto é formatação, o código não tem pontuação, pontuação não faz parte do dado. Quando conceitua errado no futuro alguma coisa dá errada e cria problema.